# Enforcing Access levels in php

Tags: php, mysql, access-levels

im making  an  MIS for  my coursework.and  i want  to know  how  to restrict access of  certain pages  to certain users.such as  if there are  admins,and  4  levels of  users,
how can i set  things in a  way that only admin can access  specific  pages etc etc etc.

btw,im using php and mysql

Comment: Add a column to store the account type. From there you just need to check if that user has the privilege to view a certain page or not.

Comment: There is no single or pre-set way of doing this with PHP. Consider reading up on [role-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) and [other types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control) of access control.

Comment: You should look into an `Access Control Lists (ACL)` as a design pattern. There are some good components you can use out of the box, such as `Zend_ACL`.